# Get workflow field value in workflow action script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a workflow, in that I have a workflow field in the entry level which captures values from "Event" record. The workflow triggers a workflow action script also. In that script I need the workflow field value which already have the event field data. Is there a way to get this in suitescript 1.0? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read value from workflow/state field in workflow-action script, you need to set it in workflow-action script paramerter.

So, you will need to create a workflow-action script parameter and in your custom-action(in your worflow state), pass it default value from workflow/state field and then you fetch its value like you would for a script parameter.

eg. In SuiteScript 1.0

```
nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', SCRIPT_PARAM_ID);
```

In SuiteScript 2.0

```
runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({ name: SCRIPT_PARAM_ID });
```

Comment: I am having the same trouble.  I added the paramter in the workflow action script, but how do I read the passed in parameter value in the script itself?  I am using suitescript 1.0. Thanks